# UICollectionView - Remove extra spacing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have an iPad application that uses to `UICollectionView` to display a grid of cells. The cells have the exact same width but different heights (as some have more text than others).

The only problem I am having is that the cells that are shorter, end up having extra spacing above/below.... this creates a bad looking collection view. It adds extra space, where no extra space is needed. I have tried to set the edge insets to 0 and the minimum line spacing to 0, but it still doesn't quite work.

Here is what my collection view looks like:

[image]

And here is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Here is my flow layout code:

```
[self.infoList registerClass:[InfoCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"InfoCell"];
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[layout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(320, 160)];
[layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
[layout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0];
[layout setMinimumLineSpacing:0];
[self.infoList setCollectionViewLayout:layout];
```

I am setting the edge insets to 0 as well:

```
-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

How can I remove the extra unnecessary space? The only way I have found that works, is to make all the cells the exact same height, but that's **not** what I want. Some cells contains for text than others, so I have to give them extra height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you can resolve this problem by custom `UICollectionViewLayout`. You should take a look at [Collection View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW1).

With the code below, I assume we have 2 row column each row, items have same width and different height.

```
const CGFloat kPadding                         = 5.f;
const NSUInteger kNumberSmallCellALine         = 2;

@interface CustomCollectionViewLayout : UICollectionViewLayout

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *layoutAttributes;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat contentHeight;

@end

@implementation CustomCollectionViewLayout

// Use this method to perform the up-front calculations needed to provide layout information.
- (void)prepareLayout{
  [super prepareLayout];

  if (!self.layoutAttributes){
    self.layoutAttributes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Calculate width of each item
    CGFloat cellWidth = (self.collectionView.frame.size.width - (kNumberSmallCellALine - 1) * kPadding) / kNumberSmallCellALine;
    // Default height of contentSize
    self.contentHeight = 0.f;
    // Height of column items on the left
    CGFloat leftColumnHeight = 0.f;
    // Height of column items on the right
    CGFloat rightColumnHeight = 0.f;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0] ; i ++){

      // Height of item at index i
      CGFloat height = i * 20 + 20;

      CGFloat xPos, yPos = 0.f;

      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        // If item on the right
        xPos = 0.f;
        yPos = leftColumnHeight;
        leftColumnHeight += height + kPadding;
      } else {
        // Item on the left
        xPos = cellWidth + kPadding;
        yPos = rightColumnHeight;
        rightColumnHeight += height + kPadding;
      }

      // Update height of contentSize after adding new item
      self.contentHeight = MAX(leftColumnHeight, rightColumnHeight);

      UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attr = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
      attr.frame = CGRectMake(xPos,
                              yPos,
                              cellWidth,
                              height);
      [self.layoutAttributes addObject:attr];
    }
  }
}

// Use this method to return the attributes for cells and views that are in the specified rectangle.
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect{
  NSMutableArray *currentAttributes = [NSMutableArray new];
  for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attr in self.layoutAttributes) {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(attr.frame, rect))
    {
      [currentAttributes addObject:attr];
    }
  }
  return currentAttributes;
}

// Use this method to return the overall size of the entire content area based on your initial calculations.
- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize{
  return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.contentHeight);
}

@end
```

Using

```
CustomCollectionViewLayout *layout = [[CustomCollectionViewLayout alloc] init];
[collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout];
```

It's a demo to resolve your issue. You should change the height of each item for being suitable with your situation.

For more information and easier understanding, you can check [My Demo Repo](https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/collection-view-odds-cell)

**NOTE** from @Supertecnoboff

You have to reload the layoutAttributes data if you are supporting multiple device orientations (eg: an iPad app). Otherwise the layout will be incorrect when rotating the device. You then need to call performBatchUpdates on the collection view to load in the new layout data.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much for this. It took me a while to figure out how to calculate the appropriate heights via the layout class, but I managed to get it working. Other than that one modification, you code works flawlessly. Thanks again.

Comment: Also just one thing to note for anyone else viewing this answer: You have to reload the layoutAttributes data if you are supporting multiple device orientations (eg: an iPad app). Otherwise the layout will be incorrect when rotating the device. You then need to call ```performBatchUpdates``` on the collection view to load in the new layout data.

Comment: Thanks @Supertecnoboff. I have updated my answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to create a [custom layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW1).

In essence, it includes the overriding of following methods:

1. [- (void)prepareLayout;](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617752-preparelayout?language=objc): to perform the up-front calculations needed to
   provide layout information.
2. [collectionViewContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617796-collectionviewcontentsize?language=objc): to return the overall
   size of the entire content area based on your initial calculations.
3. [layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617769-layoutattributesforelementsinrec?language=objc): to return the attributes for cells and views that
   are in the specified rectangle.

The `prepareLayout` method will have following implementation, This is a crude implementation you may have to tweak it according to your need.

```
- (void) prepareLayout {
    if (self.cache.count == 0) {
        UIEdgeInsets insets = self.collectionView.contentInset;
        self.contentWidth = self.collectionView.bounds.size.width - (insets.left + insets.right);

        CGFloat columnWidth = self.contentWidth / self.numberOfColumns;
        NSMutableArray *xOffsets = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSMutableArray *yOffsets = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i = 0; i < self.numberOfColumns; i++) {
            [xOffsets addObject: @(i * columnWidth)];
            [yOffsets addObject: @(0)];
        }

        int column = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0]; i++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];

            CGFloat cellHeight = arc4random_uniform(200);
            CGFloat height = self.cellPadding * 2 + cellHeight;
            CGRect frame = CGRectMake((CGFloat)[[xOffsets objectAtIndex:column] floatValue],
                                      (CGFloat)[[yOffsets objectAtIndex:column] floatValue],
                                      columnWidth,
                                      height);
            CGRect insetFrame = CGRectInset(frame, self.cellPadding, self.cellPadding);

            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
            attributes.frame = insetFrame;
            [self.cache addObject:attributes];

            self.contentHeight = MAX(self.contentHeight, CGRectGetMaxY(frame));
            [yOffsets replaceObjectAtIndex:column withObject:@([[yOffsets objectAtIndex:column]floatValue] + height)];

            column = column < (self.numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0;

            }
        }
    }
```

Find the [gist](https://gist.github.com/VivekMolkar/31cb10999e8ef5598c0f19449128c6f5) of the Custom class.